# How to save grouped fields in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this model:

```rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accesible :id, :text, :group_id
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accesible :id, :name
    has_many :messages #max 3
end
```

What is the correct way to save a new messages?

I have this in the view

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Group |  message1 |  message2 |  message3 |
+=======+===========+===========+===========+
| input | inputText | inputText | inputText |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| add new row |
+-------------+
```

By default I have one row (in view) with empty inputs. Only the message1 cannot be empty. My question is how to I save messages if always a new row is a new group.

PD: in the view form input (an empty text field) is the name of new group and inputText (an empty text field) is the text of messages.

**UPDATE**:
Message belongs to User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages
    attr_accesible :id, :name, :messages_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
end
```

Comment: are you trying to save 3 messages at once?

Comment: No. I'm trying to save various messages with different group id. If you see, each row is a group, so if you add a new row, each of these messages are associated with that group. Is a 1:N relationship. If you save a new message (or more in the same row), the group is not stored previously, then is necessary create a group for make the relation with saved messages.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass the messages back to the controller as a group? Will you be passing more than 3 messages back? i.e. is it possible to create 6 messages and then when they get submitted they belong to two groups? Do groups represent anything? Or are you just using them for formatting? It is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Also there is plenty of space on StackOverflow, please include your view code, and more info about your DB structure.

Comment: Yes, is possible. If messages are in the same row must belongs to the same group (only one). Groups represent a classification, but doesn't matter if already exists, the rule is when someone creates a new message (or messages) always will be associated to a new group. i.e If you post (in order from table example) {theName, someTextFor1, someTextFor2} and you add a new row with {theName, otherTextFor1}, you can see that despite having the same name the two groups, they are different. Note that the first one haves two messages and the second one only one message.